# Can not join group - dropping presence to unavailable resouce - ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

Hey I trying to run a local instance of ejabberd and connect to it using Adium - I am able to do so, but run into issues when trying to join a group chat.

I've tried creating a room by running `ejabberdctl create_room room1 localhost localhost` and connecting through Adium but here are the error messages I get:

```
2018-10-19 22:48:51.550 [debug] <0.2234.0>@xmpp_socket:parse:374 (tcp|<0.2234.0>)
Received XML on stream = <<"
    <presence to='room1@localhost/dan'>
        <c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' 
            node='http://pidgin.im/' hash='sha-1' 
             ver='DdnydQG7RGhP9E3k9Sf+b+bF0zo='/>
        <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
    </presence>
">>
```

and:

```
#presence{id = <<>>,type = available,lang = <<"en">>,
      from = #jid{user = <<"danmiller">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                  resource = <<"8c859086572c">>,luser = <<"danmiller">>,
                  lserver = <<"localhost">>,
                  lresource = <<"8c859086572c">>},
      to = #jid{user = <<"room1">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                resource = <<"dan">>,luser = <<"room1">>,
                lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<"dan">>},
      show = undefined,status = [],priority = undefined,
      sub_els = [#xmlel{name = <<"c">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/caps">>},
                                 {<<"node">>,<<"http://pidgin.im/">>},
                                 {<<"hash">>,<<"sha-1">>},
                                 {<<"ver">>,
                                  <<"DdnydQG7RGhP9E3k9Sf+b+bF0zo=">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #xmlel{name = <<"x">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #vcard_xupdate{hash = <<>>}],
      meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}
2018-10-19 22:48:51.552 [debug] <0.2234.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:141 local route:
#presence{id = <<>>,type = available,lang = <<"en">>,
      from = #jid{user = <<"danmiller">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                  resource = <<"8c859086572c">>,luser = <<"danmiller">>,
                  lserver = <<"localhost">>,
                  lresource = <<"8c859086572c">>},
      to = #jid{user = <<"room1">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                resource = <<"dan">>,luser = <<"room1">>,
                lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<"dan">>},
      show = undefined,status = [],priority = undefined,
      sub_els = [#xmlel{name = <<"c">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/caps">>},
                                 {<<"node">>,<<"http://pidgin.im/">>},
                                 {<<"hash">>,<<"sha-1">>},
                                 {<<"ver">>,
                                  <<"DdnydQG7RGhP9E3k9Sf+b+bF0zo=">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #xmlel{name = <<"x">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #vcard_xupdate{hash = <<>>}],
      meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}
2018-10-19 22:48:51.552 [debug] <0.2234.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:651 processing packet to full JID:
#presence{id = <<>>,type = available,lang = <<"en">>,
      from = #jid{user = <<"danmiller">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                  resource = <<"8c859086572c">>,luser = <<"danmiller">>,
                  lserver = <<"localhost">>,
                  lresource = <<"8c859086572c">>},
      to = #jid{user = <<"room1">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                resource = <<"dan">>,luser = <<"room1">>,
                lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<"dan">>},
      show = undefined,status = [],priority = undefined,
      sub_els = [#xmlel{name = <<"c">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/caps">>},
                                 {<<"node">>,<<"http://pidgin.im/">>},
                                 {<<"hash">>,<<"sha-1">>},
                                 {<<"ver">>,
                                  <<"DdnydQG7RGhP9E3k9Sf+b+bF0zo=">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #xmlel{name = <<"x">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #vcard_xupdate{hash = <<>>}],
      meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}
2018-10-19 22:48:51.553 [debug] <0.2234.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:664 dropping presence to unavailable resource:
#presence{id = <<>>,type = available,lang = <<"en">>,
      from = #jid{user = <<"danmiller">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                  resource = <<"8c859086572c">>,luser = <<"danmiller">>,
                  lserver = <<"localhost">>,
                  lresource = <<"8c859086572c">>},
      to = #jid{user = <<"room1">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                resource = <<"dan">>,luser = <<"room1">>,
                lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<"dan">>},
      show = undefined,status = [],priority = undefined,
      sub_els = [#xmlel{name = <<"c">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/caps">>},
                                 {<<"node">>,<<"http://pidgin.im/">>},
                                 {<<"hash">>,<<"sha-1">>},
                                 {<<"ver">>,
                                  <<"DdnydQG7RGhP9E3k9Sf+b+bF0zo=">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #xmlel{name = <<"x">>,
                        attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,
                                  <<"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc">>}],
                        children = []},
                 #vcard_xupdate{hash = <<>>}],
      meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}
```

I believe that I have configuration set up correctly, with `modules.mod_muc.access: all`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by paying closer attention to the documentation for the `mod_muc` module:

```
Module options:

host: HostName: This option defines the Jabber ID of the service. If the host
option is not specified, the Jabber ID will be the hostname of the virtual host
with the prefix ‘conference.’. The keyword “@HOST@” is replaced at start time with
the real virtual host name.
```

I was trying to connect and create a room at `room1@localhost` when I need to either connect instead to `room1@conference.localhost` or add `host: localhost` to my configuration under `mod_muc` section

Comment: In case you missed this: when a client tries to join a room that doesn't exist, it will be created immediately, no need to create it previously with a command. Of course, that client must have permission to create rooms (take a look to the access_create option).